# How can I change my IP using selenium WebDriver Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ip

I am parsing one site, but when I go in lately it gives the following: your IP is blocked or you send requests too often. I work with Selenium and WebDriver Chrome. Can I somehow change my IP to get around this limitation?

Comment: You can setup a proxy using selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium have no abilities to change your IP address.
This can be done with other tools / libraries.

Comment: So how can I do it?

Comment: I do not actually know. You asked how to do that with Selenium so the answer is - this is not possible with Selenium. There are several tools for this like VPN and proxy servers.